# contributions of Riemann Hypothesis to physics if the Riemann zeta function is a solution for known differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis, resultant

There are [several consequences](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17209/51189) of the Riemann hypothesis in many area as  Number theory , complex analysis $\cdots $ ,I'm interesting to know what about those consequences if the Riemann zeta function satisfy any known Algebraic differential equation then what are the  contributions  of Riemann Hypothesis to physics  if the Riemann zeta function is a solution for known differential equation?

**Note:** I meant here by satisfies any algebraic differential equation that zeta function is a solution for known algebraic differential equation

Comment: Without further context this seems like a wild guess to me. Unless I'm missing something, since I'm not that familiar with the topic

Comment: I accept your downvote, My Goal is to seek more about RH

Comment: I didn't downvote this question. Since I'm not familiar with the topic I can't make judgements here. Though I think you should really clarify the question

Comment: Concerning $\zeta$ as solution of an algebraic diﬀerential equation see this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1423720/21783).